# How to prove inadmissibility of a decision rule?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, hypothesis-testing, decision-theory

Consider two independent normal populations $X\sim N(\mu_1,1)$ and $Y\sim N(\mu_2,1)$,with $\mu_1,\mu_2 \in (-\infty,+\infty)$.

The objective is to establish a decision rule for a comparison between the two means. Suppose the action space $A = \{a_0,a_1\} $where $a_0$ corresponds to the case for $\mu_1\le\mu_2$ and otherwise, $a_1$. The loss function is given as follows:

$L((\mu_1,\mu_2),a_0)=\begin{cases}
0,&if\ \mu_1\le\mu_2\\
\mu_1-\mu_2, &if \mu_1\gt\mu_2;
\end{cases}$

$L((\mu_1,\mu_2),a_0)=\begin{cases}
\mu_2-\mu_1,&if\ \mu_1\le\mu_2\\
0, &if \mu_1\gt\mu_2;
\end{cases}$

Now given random samples (iid) $X_1,...,X_m$ and $Y_1...,Y_n$ from the above normal populations, respectively, define a decision rule of the following form:

$\delta_c(X_1,...,X_m;Y_1,...,Y_n)=\begin{cases}
a_0,&if\ \bar X\le\bar Y+c\\
a_1, &otherwise,
\end{cases}$

Consider a class of decison rules given by $D=\{\delta_c(x_1,...,x_m;y_1,...,y_n),c\in (-\infty,+\infty)\}$. Show that in this class D every decision rule is inadmissible.

I have no idea how to start with it. Any hint or help would be appreciated!

Comment: I tried my best but it seems like that this decision rule is admissible. I don't know what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can show that that decision rule is admissible.

Let $a_0 \in\{0,1\}$ and $a_1 = 1-a_0$

Note that the loss in that formulation is:

\begin{equation}
a_0(\mu_1-\mu_2)I(\mu_2<\mu_1) + (1-a_0)(\mu_2-\mu_1)I(\mu_2\geq\mu_1)
\end{equation}

Then the risk is under the proposed decision rules is:
\begin{equation}
(\mu_1 - \mu_2)P[\textrm{Type I Error}|c] + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)P[\textrm{Type II Error}|c]
\end{equation}

An alternative way to formulate the same decision rule, indexed by $c\in\mathbb{R}^+$, can be constructed using the [Karlin-Rubin Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test#The_Karlin%E2%80%93Rubin_theorem).

Let $\mu = \mu_2 - \mu_1$, then the previous decision problem corresponds to deciding between $\mu>0$ or $\mu\leq 0$, and $\bar{Y} - \bar{X} \sim \textrm{N}(\mu,\frac{1}{n_X}+\frac{1}{n_Y})$. This gives us a composite hypothesis with a scalar observation and scalar parameter; satisfying some of the requirements of the theorem.

The other requirement is that for $\mu_a >0$ and $\mu_b\leq 0$ , denoting $\mathcal{L}(\mu|\bar{Y}-\bar{X})=\textrm{N}(\bar{Y}-\bar{X}| (\mu,\frac{1}{n_X}+\frac{1}{n_Y})$, the expression:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\mathcal{L}(\mu_b|\bar{Y}-\bar{X})}{\mathcal{L}(\mu_a|\bar{Y}-\bar{X})}
\end{equation}

Is monotonically non-decreasing in $\bar{Y}-\bar{X}$, this is true because the normal distribution is in the exponential family.

By the theorem a UMP test is given by $\phi(\bar{X},\bar{Y}|c):\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \{0,1\}$, with $a_0 = \phi(\bar{X},\bar{Y}|c)$ such that:

\begin{equation}
\phi(\bar{X},\bar{Y}|c) = I(\bar{Y}-\bar{X}>c) = I(\bar{Y}>\bar{X} + c) = I(\bar{Y}+c>\bar{X}) 
\end{equation}

Which is almost surely the same decision rule as previously.

Noting that all decision rules under this binary decision space are going to have a type one and type two error. Suppose you introduced an alternative decision rule indexed by some parameter $\gamma$, call it $\chi(\bar{Y},\bar{X}|\gamma)$.

In this setting the risk for $\chi(\bar{Y},\bar{X}|\gamma)$ is going to be:

\begin{equation}
(\mu_1 - \mu_2)P[\textrm{Type I Error}|\gamma] + (\mu_2 - \mu_1)P[\textrm{Type II Error}|\gamma]
\end{equation}

But for any $\gamma$ and $\mu_1$, $\mu_2$ controlling the type I error at a specified level $\exists c$ such that :
\begin{equation}
P[\textrm{Type I Error}|\gamma] = P[\textrm{Type I Error}|c]
\end{equation}

for which:
\begin{equation}
P[\textrm{Type II Error}|\gamma] \geq P[\textrm{Type II Error}|c]
\end{equation}

because the Karlin-Rubin theorem says that the previously expressed decision decision rule is UMP.

Thus $\forall \mu_1,\mu_2$: $R(\{\mu_1,\mu_2\},\phi)\leq R(\{\mu_1,\mu_2\},\chi)$

Comment: I think this question is kind of tricky since its solution says that in this case one can take no action and have no loss. Then the proof is obvious. But anyway thank you for your answer since I think that assumption is a kind of stupid.